# Mysql Group By Last Slno (Latest Version)

Tags: php, mysql, group-by

I am trying to get value Group by last Slno

here is my table

```
slno  title       date_added  comp_name  cat
----  ----------  ----------  ---------  ----
   1  title1.0    1jan2012    AAA        cat1
   2  title 2.5   3jan2012    AAA        cat1
   3  title 30.2  5jan2012    AAA        cat1
   4  title 41.2  9jan2012    AAA        cat1
```

Here is my Query

```
SELECT slno,title,date_added
from files where cat = :cat 
GROUP by comp_name
Order By comp_name DESC limit 12
```

and output is

```
title1.0**1(slno)
```

I want to get output

```
title 41.2**4(slno)
```

Please help

EDITED ...

OK lets just group by comp_name and last slno ...

Comment: I thing you should explain several more things. For example, in the `title`column, I see the word 'title' with -- or without -- space before a value. Is this word always present? Is the space always present (visibly no)? If you group your query by `comp_name` on which criterion should the *right* `title` column be chosen?

Comment: 'COUNT(comp_name) AS theCount' i have taken count here ... i want to group ... so that i can get max count value and last updated value ... hop i make my self clear now ;)

Comment: @SylvainLeroux ok lets just group by comp_name ... with last slno ... just to make it work ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like:

```
SELECT slno,title,date_added
from files,
  (select max(slno) as mslno,comp_name from files where cat=:cat group by comp_name) t1
 where cat = :cat 
   and slno=mslno
   and files.comp_name=t1.comp_name
Order By files.comp_name DESC limit 12
```